# Most efficient way to view data in table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

Basically if I want to see what the data in a table/view looks like I use

```
select top 1000 * from ...
```

But this isn't too efficient for complex views or badly indexed tables.

I really just want to see what the data in a table looks like, e.g. the format etc.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm using SSMS 2017

*Edit for clarification:
Badly written views are endemic throughout our databases so whilst fixing these is the obvious answer it's not really a realistic one.

I suppose i was hoping for a trick i wasn't aware of, because i understand using TOP puts some sort of order into it

Comment: Fix the poor indexing?

Comment: If by "what the data looks like" you mean the column names, datatypes, etc, have a look at [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: you can set top 1 for first row result and use sp_help 'your object name' for details

Comment: If you dont need to see any data, you can use SET FMTONLY ON; 
select * from ...;
SET FMTONLY OFF;

Comment: TOP 1000 from any table is not going to be an issue at all unless the row size is huge. A view however could be problematic. But if top 1000 from a view is causing performance problems the issue is the view.

Comment: You can simply select `top 10` or even `top 1`...

Comment: @GuidoG `SET FMTONLY` is deprecated [SET FMTONLY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017); and it recommends to use the function I listed above.

Comment: No, `TOP` does *not* order the results in any way -- only `ORDER BY` does so. A `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is fast as long as the underlying query can produce its rows in a linear fashion. If it cannot, then the `TOP` can be slow as well if the optimizer cannot propagate the operation down to the base tables. If you want to gauge the results of such a query, you can try copying the view definition and using `WITH BaseTable AS (SELECT TOP(1000) * FROM dbo.BaseTable), ... SELECT TOP(1000) * FROM BaseTable JOIN ...`. Limiting the base tables this way can produce incorrect results, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight a table/view object in code and then press **ALT + F1** in SSMS IDE it will execute the equivalent command of **sp_help ‘object_name’** where object_name is the name of the highlighted object. Maybe this can give some quick information about the object you are interested in.